# Looped Timer in Excel VBA code

Tags: vba, api, loops, excel

I am new to VBA and am trying to learn some of the functionality.  What I have created is a code in excel that connects to an API and pulls data into a table.  I need it to loop for a specified period of time (9am to 4pm) and refresh every 30 seconds.  My problem is I just don't know how to accomplish this.  Here is my code Please help!  Thanks!!

Also the table being populated is setup in the following Columns: "Symbol" "Name" "Ask" "Bid" "Price" "Days Range" "1yr Target Price" "Volume" "Avg Daily Vol"

My Code:

```
Private Sub BTN_Start_Click()
    Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
    Dim Last As Integer: Last = W.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
    If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim Symbol As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To Last
        Symbol = Symbol & W.Range("A" & i).Value & "+"
    Next i
    Symbol = Left(Symbol, Len(Symbol) - 1)



    Dim url As String: url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.cvs?s=" & Symbol & "&f=snb2b3k1m2t8va2"
    Dim Http As New winhttprequest
    Http.Open "GET", url, False
    Http.send

    Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
    Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbNewLine)
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim Values As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
        sLine = Lines(i)

        If InStr(sLine, ",") > 0 Then
            Values = Split(sLine, ",")
            W.Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = Split(Split(sLine, Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34))(1), Chr(34))(0)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 6)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 5)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 4)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 6).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 3)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 7).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 2)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 8).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 1)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 9).Value = Values(UBound(Values))


        End If
    Next i
    W.Cells.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your current code put `Call Timer`

Then include this in another sub:

```
Sub Timer()
Dim CountDown As Date
CountDown = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
Application.OnTime CountDown, "BTN_Start_Click"
End Sub
```

This will run your code every 30 seconds from when you start it.

This is another option if you just want to click it and leave it...

```
Sub Timer()
If TimeValue(CStr(Now)) >= TimeValue("9:00:00 AM") And TimeValue(CStr(Now)) <= TimeValue("4:00:00 PM") Then
Dim CountDown As Date
CountDown = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
Application.OnTime CountDown, "BTN_Start_Click"
Else
Dim CountTWO As Date
CountTWO = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Application.OnTime CountTWO, "Timer"
End If
End Sub

Sub BTN_Start_Click()
Call Timer
'Your code here
End Sub
```

This will check to make sure the time is between 9 am and 4 pm... then every thirty seconds it will check again. If its between 9 am and 4 pm then it will run your code.

Comment: WOW!!  Y'all are awesome!  Thank you very much.

Comment: If one of the answers, answered your question please select it as the answer. And feel free to up vote if it or the other answers were useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the main part of your code in this loop.  It won't exit until the time is up.

```
    Do while timevalue(now()) > #9:00:00# and timevalue(now()) < #16:00:00#
      'do stuff

      Application.Wait(Now + #0:00:30#)
    loop
```

Comment: WOW!!  Y'all are awesome!  Thank you very much.